# LinkedIn API rest/shares ACCESS_DENIED. Not enough permissions to access: sharesV2.FINDER-owners

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi, linkedin-j

I'm getting the below error message when using the Linkedin-Version 202212. Also, it doesn't work with 202301. However, using 202211 is fine without any issue.

API EndPoint: `https://api.linkedin.com/rest/shares`

```
"status": 403,
"serviceErrorCode": 100,
"code": "ACCESS_DENIED",
"message": "Not enough permissions to access: sharesV2.FINDER-owners.20221201"
```

Answer (score 0):

New format API from 12.2022
source:
https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/posts-api?view=li-lms-2022-12&tabs=http

I recommend using version 202301, example link working to download posts (replace {id_organization} for your id):
[https://api.linkedin.com/rest/posts?author=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A{id_organization}&q=author&count=10](https://api.linkedin.com/rest/posts?author=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A%7Bid_organization%7D&q=author&count=10)